# Cannot insert data in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I want to insert data into order table, but the data is not inserted into the database. My code is as follows, there is no error shown. How to fix it?

```
    $saveorder= new Order;
    $saveorder->customer_id = $request->input('customer_id');
    $saveorder->vendor_id = $request->input('vendor_id');
    $saveorder->order_date= Carbon::now()->isoFormat('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $saveorder->pickup_date=$request->input('pickup_date');
    $saveorder->order_status="Pending";
    $saveorder->shipping_address=$request->input('shipping_address');
    $saveorder->amount=$request->input('amount');
    $saveorder->payment=$request->input('payment');
    $saveorder->delivery_method=$request->input('delivery_method');
    $saveorder->delievery_fee=5.00;
    $saveorder->order_notes=$request->input('order_notes');
    $saveorder->save();
```

**model**Below is order model.

```
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'order';
protected $guarded = ['id'];

protected $fillable = [
    'order_date',
    'pickup_date',
    'order_status',
    'shipping_address',
    'amount',
    'payment',
    'delivery_method',
    'delivery_fee',
    'phone',
    'order_notes',
    'customer_id',
    'vendor_id',
];

protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'integer',
];
```

**migration** Below are my migration file.

```
Schema::create('order', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('order_date');
        $table->date('pickup_date');
        $table->string('order_status');
        $table->string('shipping_address');
        $table->decimal('amount', 10, 2);
        $table->string('payment');
        $table->string('delivery_method');
        $table->string('delivery_fee');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('order_notes');
        $table->unsignedInteger('customer_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('vendor_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

No error is shown, laravel save() function does not work.

Comment: can u add other codes  EX: model, migration file

Comment: any error message?

Comment: Add the primary key to guarded in your model. `protected $guarded = ['id'];`. It will work.

Comment: @Ankit Singh still cannot work.

Comment: @habeebdev no error

Comment: Could you include your function in try-catch block. And log the error with `info($e->getMessage())`.

Comment: And add `@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif` in your blade file

Comment: thanks, problem solved. one of my column name wrong.

Comment: @Milayo I have framed the answer as per your problem. So please accept it and give me upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug your code a bit. Follow the steps below.

*First, update your blade file by adding below code. This will display all the errors related to validation*

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

*Second, wrap your method to save the data in `try-catch` block. It will show you all errors related to your code inside the function to save the data.*

```
try {
    // your code goes here
} catch (Exception $e) {
    info($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$saveorder= new Order();
    $saveorder->customer_id = $request->customer_id;
    $saveorder->vendor_id = $request->vendor_id;
    $saveorder->order_date= Carbon::now()->isoFormat('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $saveorder->pickup_date=$request->pickup_date;
    $saveorder->order_status="Pending";
    $saveorder->shipping_address=$request->shipping_address;
    $saveorder->amount=$request->amount;
    $saveorder->payment=$request->payment;
    $saveorder->delivery_method=$request->delivery_method;
    $saveorder->delievery_fee=5.00;
    $saveorder->order_notes=$request->order_notes;
    $saveorder->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use create function its good solution and clean code and give it validated input
or collect all in new var and pass it to function create
save method it's used commonly with case update object not with insert new object in database finally make dd() for the request to ensure all inputs you are inserting are come in request and ensure data type in the database compatible

Answer (score -1):

This is a proper way to save data.

```
// validate if you need
$data = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);

// otherwise
$data = $request->all();

// then add extra fields
$data['order_date'] = Carbon::now()->isoFormat('YYYY-MM-DD');
$data['order_status'] = "Pending";
$data['delievery_fee'] = 500;

// and save
Order::create($data);
```

```
class Order extends Model
{
   public $guarded = []; // make sure you validate the data if you use this. and remove $protected if you have.
}
```

Comment: I can get all the $request data, but when i add create() or save(), the data does not store in database and no error is shown